# Support for broadcast beacon in React Native

Tags: ibeacon, react-native, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

How can I broadcast beacon in React Native? Is there any packages supporting both iOS and Android? I found [this package](https://github.com/williamtran29/react-native-ibeacon-simulator), but supports only iOS. I don't see anything which supports for Android alone or both iOS and Android.

Answer (score 0):

[This React native Beacon library supports for both iOS and Android](https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager).

[This is another library (Even though it is for Konkat.io beacons, they says that it will works for all beacons.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-kontaktio)